# What's the suitable HTTP error for non requested required data

Tags: http, web, http-error

In my case there is no parameters required. In other words, the application does not expect any data via post, get or put. However, in the implementation a stored list of items in session variable should be defined first i.e. something like shopping cart items, the user collect items, and then go to the action below, otherwise, it should throw an HTTP error. Checkout the example below:

```
public function actionCreate(){
  if(count(Yii::$app->session->get('versesList',[])) > 0){
    // Do the logic
  }
  else{
    throw new \yii\web\BadRequestHttpException(Yii::t('app', 'You must collect some verses first!')); 
  }
}
```

I don't know exactly, if the 400 bad request is the proper error code or not. I have tried reading [List of HTTP status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) on the Wikipedia but I have gotten confused among some of the other HTTP errors such as: `406 Not Acceptable`, `412 Precondition Failed`,`422 Unprocessable Entity`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP 400, since you are requesting an operation the server doesn't know how to handle (so it's a bad request).

[RFC2731](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231) states the following:

> The 400 (Bad Request) status code indicates that the server cannot or will not process the request due to something that is perceived to be a client error (e.g., malformed request syntax, invalid request message framing, or deceptive request routing).

Answer (score 1):

`400` is definitely fine for this case, but if you want to get more specific:

it sounds like the user needs to do *some other HTTP request* for this HTTP request to be valid. It's common to use `409 Conflict` for these cases.

I wrote a bit more about this with additional examples on my blog, if it's interesting: https://evertpot.com/http/409-confict